# How do you make slimes not spawn randomly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you make slimes not spawn? They are very annoying especially in a superflat world. I want to make them not spawn randomly.
In 1.16

Comment: Please [ask a new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead. Also, don't edit the intent of answers please.

Answer (score 3):

I see two simple ways of doing this:

- Use `/gamerule doMobSpawning false` to disable spawning of *all* mobs in your superflat world.
- Use a repeating command block to `/tp @e[type=minecraft:slime] ~ -1000 ~`, so that they don't split into multiple slimes.
- Set the difficulty to peaceful.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** Use 2 repeating command blocks which contains the following:

1. `/kill @e[type=minecraft:slime]`
2. `/kill @e[type=minecraft:item,name=Slimeball]`

---

Apart from [**@ExpertCoder14**'s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376113/how-do-you-make-slimes-not-spawn-randomly/376114#376114), you can also use another repeating command block with `/kill @e[type=minecraft:slime]`.

Although this doesn't stop slime from spawning, it at least gets rid of it, though it could be a mess dealing with, because remember, there are slimeballs when slime are killed.

It is easily managed with another repeating command block with `/kill @e[type=minecraft:item,name=Slimeball]`, and you can get rid of them.

Problem solved, no more slimes in the way.

Comment: The only issue with this answer is that it will show the constant death animation and them dividing; still works nonetheless